# Is it necessary to use std::move when swapping two objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, move-semantics

Is `std::move` necessary in the following snippet?

```
std::function<void(int)> my_std_function;

void call(std::function<void(int)>&& other_function)
{
  my_std_function.swap(std::move(other_function));
}
```

As far as I know `call()` accepts a rvalue reference.. but since the rvalue reference is itself an lvalue, in order to call `swap(std::function<void(int)>&&)` I have to re-cast this to an rvalue reference with `std::move`

Is my reasoning correct or `std::move` can be omitted in this case (and if it can, why?)

Comment: Seems like you want to issue operator= instead of swap here. And then, yes, use move.

Answer (score 18):

`std::function::swap` does not take its parameter by rvalue reference. It's just a [regular non-`const` lvalue reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/swap). So `std::move` is unhelpful (and probably shouldn't compile, since rvalue references aren't allowed to bind to non-`const` lvalue references).

`other_function` also doesn't need to be an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 11):

The signature is

```
void std::function<Sig>::swap( function& other )
```

so code should not compile with `std::move` (msvc has extension to allow this binding :/)

As you take r-value reference, I think that a simple assignment is what you want in your case:

```
std::function<void(int)> my_std_function;

void call(std::function<void(int)>&& other_function)
{
  my_std_function = std::move(other_function); // Move here to avoid copy
}
```

Comment: @Dean would this magic include turning a very fast computer into a hot block of plastic merely by installing it?

Comment: @Dean Er, what? Why is it "fantastic magic" to allow rvalue refs to bind to non-const lvalue refs? Was that sarcasm?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it doesn't make a difference as `std::function::swap` takes a non-const lvalue reference. It shouldn't even compile with `std::move`.

If you used a function which *did* allow rvalues, then you *would* need to call `std::move` as `other_function` is an lvalue, even though the type of it is an rvalue reference. For example:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo()=default;
    Foo(const Foo&) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; }
    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << "move" << std::endl; }
};

void bar (Foo&& a) {
    Foo b {a};            //copy
    Foo c {std::move(a)}; //move
}
```

Comment: This adds valuable information instead of just mentioning that `swap()` takes a reference, which I think wasn't really the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in a sense — to get an rvalue again you'd need `std::move`.

However, the `swap` call doesn't need an rvalue or an rvalue reference — just a plain ol' lvalue ref.

So you're good to go without the `std::move` cast.

In terms of move semantics, a swap operation is pretty low-level. You'll find that most useful moves are ultimately implemented by a series of swaps, so it makes sense that the swaps themselves don't use move semantics. Really, how would they?