# Why do standard library classes not overload swap() for rvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, move-semantics, std

STL classes define `swap()` method as `void swap(A&)`, taking an l-value reference. See for example [std::vector::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap), or the question [Is it necessary to use std::move when swapping two objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593898/is-stdmove-necessary-here)

Such definition means we cannot swap with r-values, since r-value won't bind to However, I see no harm in swapping with r-values. Construct it, steal from it, place some guts in it, destroy it. Done. We can add another overload `void swap(A&&)` to make it happen.

I see only one reason why we do not have this overload out of the box. Because instead of writing

```
v.swap(rvalue);
```

It is better to write

```
v = rvalue;
```

And instead of swapping we will trigger move-assignment, which is even more efficient. Am I right that this reason is valid? Is this the only reason?

Comment: Why not write `rvalue.swap(v)`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Right, if I can write `rvalue.swap(v)`, why I cannot write the opposite? `swap` operation is commutative, so I'd expect it to be accessible in both ways.

Comment: Member functions aren't really commutative anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the original move papers actually specified this for the containers:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1858.html#23.2%20-%20Sequences

And later propagated to `shared_ptr` and `function`:

http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#743

http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#770

Swapping with rvalue arguments fell out of favor with LWG 884:

http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#884

And N2844 subsequently removed *all* rvalue swaps:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2844.html

I'm not positive this was a good move.  However with the more modern `shrink_to_fit()` way of reducing memory, I'm not positive it matters, since that was the main use case of swapping with rvalues.

Answer (score 2):

You've more or less answered your own question.

We needed

```
  v.swap(rvalue);
```

in the bleak dark-ages leading up to C++11.  Since then, we can explicitly grab a hold of rvalues to do as we please.

Allowing `swap` to take rvalues would be taking a step backwards

Answer (score 2):

The point of "moving" is that you don't care about the state of the source once you've moved from it. This is totally different with `swap`, where both states are well-defined afterwards.

IOW, `A::swap(A&& rhs)` at the same time does and does not guarantee what state `rhs` will be in afterwards.

Comment: Disagree. `A::swap(A&& rhs)` strictly defines the state of `rhs` after the call. The fact that `rhs` is automatically destroyed at the end of the statement, does not matter here.

Comment: @Mikhail: Why would `A::swap(A&& rhs)` strictly define the state of a moved-from variable? You seem to be introducing one special member function that is exempt from the rule that moved-from variables are left in an unspecified state.

Comment: Ok, agree. I forgot we cannot rely on the fact that e.g. a moved-from vector is empty.